# Is there a way to make year constant in date_from and date_to in Django DateField and count the number of days from those two fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In Django model i have two fields called date_from , date_to and number of days. The date_from and date_to are supposed to only have date and month so i need to set year with a default value which is don't know how to do.The number_of_days must be the number of days calculation from date_from and date_to. I need help on this issue.

I'm new to django so i don't know how to do this

```
date_from = models.DateField()
date_to = models.DateField()
no_of_days = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

so lets say the date_from needs to take in 22-2 and date_to as 22-3 without year from calender and the no_of_days must show as 30 counting the number of days from date_from and date_to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it as a field but could do it as a property (it won't be saved to the database, cannot be sorted on etc but is accessible within your program)

```
@property
no_of_days = (self.date_from - self.date_to).days
```

or you could overwrite the save class

```
class Save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.no_of_days = (self.date_from - self.date_to).days
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```